# How to use local relay with Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, network-configuration, guard-node

I am running a tor relay (which has the guard flag) in my LAN at an IP like 192.168.0.103. I would like to have Tor Browser use this relay as a guard/entry node so that all the tor traffic goes through that computer (for traffic shaping).

Following [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/how-to-tell-my-tor-browser-to-use-a-certain-relay-as-entry-point) I tried using `EntryNodes` – with the fingerprint, with local IP or with the public IP – in torrc, but it fails to connect to the network. In some cases it just keeps connecting forever, in others it gives something like:

```
17/09/16 11:53:24.800 [NOTICE] 1 entries in guards 
17/09/16 11:53:25.800 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
17/09/16 11:53:26.800 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
17/09/16 11:53:27.800 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
17/09/16 11:53:28.800 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
```

However, with the same fingerprint I can connect from another network (with different public IP).

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Could you share the relay fingerprint? I was able to get the Tor Browser to use custom entry nodes just fine. The correct syntax in torrc is `EntryNodes $relayfingerprint` and relays that are used as exits cannot be used for anything else (this is hard-coded).

Comment: I've verified that I can connect to the same entry node using the fingerprint when I don't share the same IP (tethering through a cell phone instead, with the same configuration). The issue is not the relay, but that the tor browser cannot connect when on the same lan and public IP.

Comment: Routing issue then, unrelated to Tor.

Comment: It is very easy. Tell Tor Browser in network settings that your ISP blocks. Then fill 192.168.0.103:9001 into the custom bridge field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using it as a bridge if I need to use a Tor Browser through it, but usually I'm routing all traffic through Tor node at my home: it's simple and secure. I'm using `iptables` for it and local `bind` setup.

Comment: So you have made it work when they are in the same network as in my case? What did you need to configure with iptables?

Comment: @user14363 like [this](https://github.com/netsafe/linux-builder/blob/master/rpi2-rc.local)